# Step failure in theta estimation using bam() in mgcv

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am using [?bam](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/bam.html) in [mgcv 1.8-24](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html), and when I'm using the negative binomial family I sometimes get a warning that says:

> ```
> In estimate.theta(theta, family, y, mu, scale = scale1, wt = G$w, :  
> step failure in theta estimation
> ```

The results from the model fit still seem reasonable.  I can often get the warning to go away just by changing `k` slightly for my smooth term (I am using mostly parametric terms).  After adjusting `k` and getting rid of the warning, the results look the same.

I haven't been able to find any description of this warning. What is a "step failure", and is it something that I need to worry about?

Comment: This question is probably still bound up in the implementation in the R code, but after the edit, it seems to me it is a legitimate statistical question.  I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Can you provide a small example dataset & simple code that will reproduce this error?  Although [stats.SE] isn't an R tech support site (hence the prior hold), it may be necessary for people to determine the answer.

Comment: Well, I've found that the warning goes away when I don't use discretization (an option that makes fitting faster), which makes me think that it IS more of a software issue and less of a statistical question.  If anyone knows the details of the algorithm and wants to share why this might be, that would be great, but otherwise this can be closed.

Comment: It's up to you, @dante. If you want, you can delete the thread yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but after hitting this exact error I can confirm that it seems to be a software issue. Setting `discrete=FALSE` in the bam gives identical results and residuals to `discrete=TRUE` but without the error. Hope that helps the next person who stumbles across the same issue!

Comment: It's not a software issue; you are fitting with different data depending on the value of `discrete` and this warning can occur outside of fitting with `bam()`. It indicates a problem during optimization of one of the parameters (no steps the algorithm took to walk downhill to hopefully the min of the penalised log likelihood actually resulted in a reduction in that criterion but that convergence criteria weren't met at the current estimates of model coefs) and likely that there is some issue or incompatibility between the data and the model you are fitting to them.